# Deploying Dacpacs to an Availability Group in a locked-down production

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, production-environment, sql-server-data-tools

My DBA and I are trying to work out how to effectively use Microsoft's Database projects and the Dacpacs they generate to simplify our production deployment system.

Ideally, I would be able to build and/or publish the `.sqlproj`, generating a `.dacpac` file, which can then be uploaded to the production server and used to upgrade the database from whatever version it was to the latest version.  This is similar to how we're doing website deployments, where I publish to a package, and then that package is uploaded to the server and imported into IIS.

However, we can't work out how to make this work. The DBA has already created the database and added it to our Availability Groups.  And every time we try to apply the Dacpac, it tries to adjust settings which it can't because of the AGs.

Nothing I've been able to do has managed to create a `.dacpac` file which *doesn't* try to impose settings on the database.   The closest option I've found will exclude them when publishing, but as best as I can tell you can't publish to an inaccessible database, and only the DBA has access to the production server.

**Can I actually use dacpacs this way?**

Comment: Why can't you access them, is it your permissions or is the database the read only secondary?

Comment: @EdElliott - It's mostly a question of access.  The production environment is locked down such that it's only accessible *at all* from a machine which we have to RDP into, and that machine is only accessible over a VPN.  The jump-box has SSMT, but not VS, and we only have read-only access through it (except the DBA).

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this, firstly how do you stop deploying settings you don't want to deploy - can you give an example of one of the settings that doesn't apply?

For the second part where you do not have access to the SQL Server there are a few different ways to handle this:

- Use an offline copy to generate the deploy script
- Get the DBA to generate the deploy script
- Get the DBA to deploy using the dacpac
- Get read only access to the database

Option 1: "Use an offline copy to generate the deploy script"

You need to compare the dacpac to something and if you do not have a TDS connection (default instance default port tcp:1433) then you can use a version of the database that matches production either through:

- Use log shipping to restore a copy of production somewhere you can access it
- Get a development db and production in sync, then every release goes to the dev and prod databases, ensuring that they stay in sync

The log shipped copy is the easiest, if it is to a development server you can normally have server permissions to give you acesss or you can create the correct permissions at the database level but not on the production server level.

If the data is sensitive then the log shipped copy might not be appropriate so you could try to keep a development and production database in sync but this is difficult and requires that the DBA be "well trained" into not running anything that isn't first run against the db database as well.

Once you have access to a database that has exactly the same schema as the production database you can use sqlpackage.exe /action:script to generate a deploy script, in fact because it isn't the production database you can generate the script as part of your CI process :).

Option 2: "Get the DBA to generate the deploy script"

This is to get the DBA to copy the dacpac to the productions server and to use sqlpackage.exe that will be in "Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Sql Server\Version\DAC\bin" folder to compare the dacpac to the database and generate a script that he can review before deploying.

Option 3: "Get the DBA to generate the deploy script"

This is simlar to option 2 but instead of generating a script he deploys in SSMS he just use sqlpackage.exe /Action:Publish to deploy the changes directly.

Option 4: "Get read only access to the database"

This is actually my preferred as it means that you always build scripts against what is guaranteed to be the state of production (as it is production). In your case you would need to get the tcp port between your machine or ideally your build machine and the SQL Server and then you will need these permissions:

https://the.agilesql.club/Blogs/Ed-Elliott/What-Permissions-Do-I-Need-To-Generate-A-Deploy-Script-With-SSDT

As I said option 4 is always my preferred but I understand that it isn't always possible.

Option 2 + 3 are fraught with worry as you will be running scripts that haven't been tested anywhere, with option 4 and 1 you can generate the scripts and then deploy to a test / QA database as long as they themselves have the same schema as production. The scripts can also go through a code review process.

If you do option 2 / 3 then I would create a batch file or powershell script that drives sqlpackage.exe and if they deploy from a different server that doens't have sqlpackage.exe then you can copy the DAC folder to that machine and run sqlpackage from that, you do not have to actually install it (you may need to also copy in the Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll from the "Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Sql Server\Version\SDK\Assemblies" folder.

I hope this helps, if you have any more questions feel free to post here or ping me  :)

ed

Comment: We had ours setup so the build box had read privs to all dbs and their schema so it could generate the appropriate deploy report and change script. We could then review those from the build artifacts and verify them.  **It sounds like your problem is trying to do an ALTER DATABASE. There's a command/option to not do this. Create a Publish Profile that doesn't try to update the Database settings and you should be fine.  Your DBA should be able to run the appropriate options then to gen the diff report, script, and/or publish as needed.

Comment: Are options 2/3 significantly different than choosing the "Upgrade" option in SSMS?  I had assumed that that was just a GUI for SqlPackage, so if the dacpac didn't work in one, it would still be a problem in the other.  I'll talk to the DBA about option 1.  Although I definitely worry about changes being applied to the offline copy and then not making it to production.

Comment: @PeterSchott - Yes, the ALTER DATABASE is the problem.  The frustrating part is that the publish profiles need a connection string, which I can't usefully give it without this answer's option 1 (which is possibly feasible) or 4 (which is entirely not, for regulatory reasons).

Comment: I thought it was possible to override the connection for a Publish Profile, but I could be wrong. In any case, you should be able to pass a command line option to tell it not to try to apply the DB settings. I know that's an option somewhere for SQLPackage.  As for #4, why is it not possible for the DBA to run this to gen the script against the live copy of the data?

Comment: We're having the same problem with the .dacpac file trying to ALTER DATABASE, which isn't allowed when using an Availability Group.You've mentioned using a publish profile parameter or command line parameter to disable this. Do you by chance know the actual parameter(s) we'd need to use? Got a link to any documentation by chance?

Comment: I found the documentation for command line parameters that can be provided when deploying a .dacpac file: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx. I haven't had a chance to play with them yet, but I'm guessing `ScriptDatabaseOptions` might be the one I'd want to use in order to prevent any ALTER DATABASE statements from being executed.